# Python Selenium Always get empty text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the text in the elements with li class ="tooltip icon-bed" from the below html and I expect to get value "2" in this example but I always get an empty value instead.

```
<div class="listing-info-mobile">
     <p class="icon-location">
                Residencial            </p>
     <div class="details">
         <p class="price">
                   1,654,080                </p>
         <ul class="features">
                 <li original-title="Recámaras" class="tooltip icon-bed">2</li>
                 <li original-title="Baños" class="tooltip icon-bath">1</li>
                 <li original-title="Superficie (m²)" class="tooltip icon-building-area">69</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the part of my code that is trying to get the text:

```
extract=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='features']")
for item in extract:
            print item.find_element_by_class(".//li[@class='tooltip icon-bed']").text
```

It seems to find the elements but text is always empty.  Any idea?

Comment: Is this text visible on the page??

Comment: Because the text needs to be directly in that element, features does not contains any text, contains other elements and those elements contain text.

Comment: Try once in one line as `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.features > li.icon-bed").get_attribute("textContent")` and let me know

Answer (score 4):

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.features > li.tooltip.icon-bed").get_attribute("innerHTML")
This should do the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

get_attribute("innerHTML") worked for me. Apparently, when you are using Django/Python, .text is not working. It always comes as blank. However, innerHTML is coming as expected and hence assertion works.